# Dynamic Namespace in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to create a dynamic namespace in a javascript class?

I'm running into an issue where I need to use this class twice on the same page but it uses the same namespace in both spots so it's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always instantiate the class like this:

```
window['stuff'] = new Component()
window['stuff1'] = new Component()
```

so then you can refer to this instance as window.stuff and window.stuff1

is this what you mean?

Comment: ALSO, you should never use window for this stuff, but this will for for other globals as well:

Answer (score 0):

```
var namespace1 = {};
var namespace2 = {};

var myObjMaker = function() {
    this.a = blah;
    this.function = bluh;
}

var makeObjInNS1 =  myObjMaker.apply(namespace1);
var makeObjInNS2 =  myObjMaker.apply(namespace2);
var makeGlobalObj =  myObjMaker.apply(this);
```